# why when the problem of a closed question is resolved instead of reopen it is again closed with a new reason?

Tags: discussion

it is possible that there are more than one reason for closing a question. but how to ensure moderators are not closing questions based on sectarian and only want to seek an excuse for closing?

why a moderator should change his mind about closing a question? and change the reason of closing if it is really closed based on real reason?

this is not an accuse of sectarian but a question to warn moderators also to ensure moderators do not work based on sectarian.

as example this reason of closing this question is changed after removing list asking (the first reason of closing)

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/is-research-about-checking-authenticity-of-the-hadithes-in-bukhari-collection-pe#comment10023_5325

Answer (score 2):

> but how to ensure moderators are not closing questions based on
>   sectarian and only want to seek an excuse for closing?

This is what meta is clearly meant for. Discuss what you feel is not right, in an *academic* manner. StackExchange, way I have seen it, is fairly democratic and transparent. If you feel the closure and/or the deletion was unfair, you want more clarification on the closure reason or anything else about the site bring your case on meta. Like I'm going to do in case of [*Was the return of the sun witnessed elsewhere around the globe?*](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/11087/3175)'s putting on-hold, after possibly making some minor edits to it.

> why a moderator should change his mind about closing a question?

You answered that question yourself. *"it is possible that there are more than one reason for closing a question"* you tackled one after by editing the question but might have missed the other one(s).

> this is not an accuse of sectarian but a question to warn moderators
>   also to ensure moderators do not work based on sectarian.

Moderators (minus [Community](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/-1) ;-) ) are mortals they can make mistakes. By default they should be taken as [*moderators*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_forum#Moderators) and in case you can solidly *prove* anything against them then you can head to [meta.so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) and worst case contact [StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/221866).

Unfortunately, I can't view the deleted post you provided the link of because of [rep limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: in voting model websites the only thing minority members can do is dua. Quran is against majority and loving minority. only search اکثر in Quran to see what says God about majority. Islam disagree liberal democracy and voting. but this site is based on voting and liberal democracy and so what the majority wants will be imposed and majority always justify. SE managers redirect you to mods of this site again. so the only thing is dua.

Comment: *so what the majority wants will be imposed and majority always justify*. This statement seems to be quite assumptious, seeing that majority (observed approximation) of users want to troll, spam, debate and quarrel on SE sites. Yet the utmost minority on SE site are striving to maintain the decorum and the state of these sites. Sticking to the core fundamentals *"Just Questions"* and *"Just Answers"*, and moderated by *"you"*. These things are commendable and a minority did it (made a network you don't want to leave or be ruined). Cntd..

Comment: Be optimistic. And as [Shog9](http://stackexchange.com/users/620) said [*"Be your own worst critic"*](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/q/790/3175).